# Quando é que se comecou a utilizar o termo "abelhinha" para designar táxis ? Ou sera para designar carro?

Tags: significado, português-europeu, significado-em-contexto, regionalismo

Quando é  que se comecou a utilizar o termo "abelhinha" para designar  carro? Mais recentemente muitas pessoas pensao que representa taxi

Comment: Vale notar que seria utilizado apenas na ilha de Madeira, de acordo com essas fontes: https://www.bloom-consulting.com/journal/5-curiosities-about-madeira/3/  e  https://ncultura.pt/300-expressoes-que-so-um-madeirense-entende/ .

Comment: Em 1950, de acordo com o "Vocabulário Madeirense", de Fernando Augusto da Silva ([e-print](http://www.vetbiblios.pt/DIVERSOS/Actividades_Veterinarias/VocPopularMad.pdf)), "abelhinha" significava "carro pequeno", não taxi. E [essa página](https://placido.webnode.com/ilha-da-madeira/termos-madeirenses/) afirma que o termo significa "_Táxi de fora do Funchal pois possuíam em tempos passados um "A"(Aluguer) em vez de "Táxi" nas portas._"

Comment: Adicionei a _tag_ de "português europeu", pois Madeira [costuma](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arquip%C3%A9lago_da_Madeira) ser considerado um território europeu, e porque as fontes que encontrei (esse [artigo](https://ahm-abm.madeira.gov.pt/index.php/ahm/article/view/3) e essa [resposta](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/os-dialectos-em-portugal/10919#) do Ciberdúvidas) se referirem ao madeirense como um dialeto do português europeu.

Comment: Cheguei a ouvir abelhinha para designar carro , há muitos anos atras

Comment: Onde ouviste "abelhinha" para designar carro, @ClMend?

Comment: Uma pessoa , que se estivesse viva teria 110 anos